# Printing out all columns separately in a 2D array except the 1st column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm currently trying to print out all columns separately except the first column in a 2D array. In my code I currently have x printing the first column and y printing the second. How would I go about having y print out the second, third etc columns?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    from sys import argv
    from scipy.signal import chirp, find_peaks, peak_widths
    #from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
    import numpy as np
    #import scipy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
    import os

    FILENAME = "test.txt"
    f = open(FILENAME,"r")
    arr=[]

    with open(FILENAME) as inpfile:
        line = inpfile.readline()
        while line:
            tmp = line.split()
            arr.append(tmp)
            line = inpfile.readline()

    ARR = np.array(arr, dtype = float)
    x = ARR[:,0]
    y = ARR[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up slicing.  You want to specify columns 1 to the end, a simple extension:

```
y = ARR[:,1:]
```